# exec("ls") not returning full "ls"

Tags: php

So I have this PHP code which is pretty simple.

```
$string = exec("ls foo");
```

In `foo` I have 4 files

```
foo
bar
hi
bye
```

But `echo $string` returns `bye`

How can I make it return all of the files? Is it not working because `ls` separates by tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

> **Return Values**
>
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a command and have all the data from the command passed directly back without any interference, use the ˋpassthru()ˋ function.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use exec for file operations. PHP has a full set of functions for that purpose. You can start with dir:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.dir.php

Answer (score 0):

Boris' suggestion is good, but it's a bit complicated to figure it out.

Simply use this

```
passthru ('ls');
```

or this to 'prettify' it

```
echo "<pre>";
passthru ('ls');
echo "</pre>";
```